# ToDoList with datepicker.js save local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm learning JS, and want to write own `ToDoList` on `js+html+css+sortable+datepicker.js` and save it in the local storage. I found  an example without `datepicker`. How can I write my js in a function `AddListItem`(I think) to add input value `datepicker` to tag '`li`' "some input date": "some input text"? Help me, please.

`Datepicker` not work, but in my `localhost` its work good.

```
`https://codepen.io/sinovdeath/pen/BeZEzB`
```

Comment: Could you change language of codepen to English for the better understanding ?

Comment: I've already changed language.

Comment: #container used twice in CSS, for the fix

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML Solution:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add date" id="datepicker">
```

You can use:

```
 <input type="date" placeholder="Add date" id="datepicker">
```

And the calender will be available!

Comment: yes, but i want to add this input in my function addListItem. How can I do it? When I add todoTask and date, submit it, and then LI will be formate Date: Task